# Is it possible for iOS triggering onNewIntent() in aos?

Tags: android, nfc, hce, nfc-p2p, core-nfc

I hope to develop applications to **exchange data via NFC between aOS and iOS**. 
For **aOS to iOS**, it is possible to emulate a tag in android and read from iOS. 
However, as **iOS CoreNFC** did not open up **HCE mode**. I'm wondering whether there's any method to trigger the **onNewIntent()** function in **aOS** by **iOS** so that I can pass data from iOS to aOS through **onNewIntent()**

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to emulate a NFC Tag in Android, but you don't use `onNewIntent` that is for reading NFC cards

See the Host Card Emulation documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce

You will then need to emulate a Type 4 NFC card that is storing a NDEF message with the Android Device as iOS will only read (and write in iOS 13) NDEF messages from Type 4 cards.

The specification on how to emulate a Type 4 Card with NDEF on it is in Section 5 of http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-4-Tag_2.0.pdf

Comment: Yup I can read aos hce from iOS nfc reader app however I want to ask whether I can write value from iOS to aos in hce mode?

Comment: With iOS 13 you can write NDEF so as long as your Host Card Emulation handles the Update C-APDU D6h then data can be received as well as sent. See section 5.4.7 of spec.